# Chrome - Strange Mouse Events from Select element

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, select, mouseover

The site I use for work has a drop down menu at the top and then form content underneath. Clicking on Selects within forms is causing the menu items to be selected as though the user has hovered over them.

I've managed to replicate the problem on an example page, take a look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/86d1nx7x/1/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
        <script src="../../resources/jquery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <title></title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(
            function()
            {
        $('#nav li a').on('mouseover',
          function()
          {
            var id = '#menu_' + $(this).parent('li').attr('id').substr(5),
                menu = $(id),
                offset = $(this).offset(),
                xpos = offset.left,
                ypos = offset.top + $(this).height();
            $('.menu').hide();
            menu.css({
              'left': (xpos + 2) + 'px',
              'top': ypos + 'px'
            }).show();

          }
        );
        $('#nav li a').on('mouseout',
          function()
          {
            //$('.menu').hide();
          }
        );

            }
        );
        </script>
    <style>
      body, div, ul, li, a {
        padding:0px;
        margin:0px;
      }
      #nav {
        position: absolute;
        padding:0px 0px 0px 10px;
        top: 0px;
        width: 100%;
        height: 30px;        
        background-color:#FFF;

        -webkit-transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
      }
      #nav:hover {
        background-color:#000;
      }
      #nav ul{
        list-style-type:none;
      }
      #nav li {
        float:left;
      }
      #nav a {
        display:block;
        margin:0px 10px 0px 0px;
        height:30px;
        line-height:30px;
        padding:0px 10px 0px 10px;

        background-color:#AAA;
      }
      #nav .menu {
        display:none;
        width:200px;
        height:100px;
        position:absolute;
        background-color:#BBB;
      }      
      #content {
        padding: 5px;
        margin: 35px 0px 0px 0px;
        background-color:#CCC;
      }
      #content .columns .column {
        display:block;
        float:left;
        width:200px;
      }
      #content .columns .column select {
        display:block;
      }
      .clear {
        clear:both;
      }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>

  <div id="content">

    <div class="columns">
      <div class="column">
        <select>
          <option value="1">Select 1</option>
        </select>
        <select>
          <option value="2">Select 2</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <select>
          <option value="3">Select 3</option>
        </select>
        <select>
          <option value="4">Select 4</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <select>
          <option value="5">Select 5</option>
        </select>
        <select>
          <option value="6">Select 6</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <select>
          <option value="7">Select 7</option>
        </select>
        <select>
          <option value="8">Select 8</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="clear"></div>        

  </div>

  <div id="nav">
    <ul>
      <li id="link_1"><a href="#1">Link One</a></li>
      <li id="link_2"><a href="#2">Link Two</a></li>
      <li id="link_3"><a href="#3">Link Three</a></li>
      <li id="link_4"><a href="#4">Link Four</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="menu" id="menu_1">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="menu" id="menu_2">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="menu" id="menu_3">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="menu" id="menu_4">&nbsp;</div>
  </div>


    </body>
</html>
```

There are mouseover events on the menu which are getting fired when I click on Selects 2 and 4 below. They seem to have the right xpos but the ypos is 0.

I've been struggling to pin down the error to a specific Chrome version or OS, so If you experience the error then please leave a comment saying what version of Chrome and OS you were using - I'm using Chrome 37 64bit on Linux.

Thanks

UPDATE: This problem was present up to version 39 (Latest version as of Nov '14). The only solution I've found was to revert to version 34.

UPDATE: I've just updated to 41.0.2272.89 (64-bit) and the problem seems to be fixed!

Comment: Is this also happening in Firefox?

Comment: No, I've only noticed it in Chrome so far.

Comment: In [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/86d1nx7x/3/) still happens?

Comment: Yes still happening - are you able to see the strange behaviour in the original fiddle yourself?

Comment: Yes, I am getting the same issue, anyone got any solution?